# How to set the cron job for indexing in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I need to setup cron job for indexing. Cron job run every day once.

Answer (score 1):

You can create controller for reindexing and Add this controller in your cronjob :

```
.....

/**
 * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory
 */
protected $_indexerFactory;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_indexerCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory
){
   $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
   $this->_indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
}

// Function for reindexing
public function reIndexing(){
   $indexerCollection = $this->_indexerCollectionFactory->create();
   $indexer_ids = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();
   foreach ($indexer_ids as $id) {
   $reindex_id = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load($id);
   $reindex_id->reindexAll($id); // For reindexing all
   //$reindex_id->reindexRow($id); // For specific reindex.
}

.....
```

Or you can set it using crontab -e if you are using ubuntu.

```
0 22 * * * php /path/to/your/site/root/bin/magento index:reindex <index_type>
```

This cron will execute once in a day at 10 pm.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ubuntu you can open configured cron jobs by using command **`crontab -e`**

Let us assume that PHP is located in **`/user/bin`** and you installed Magento 2 in /var/www/html/magento2 directory.

Now let's say you want to run indexer every day once, you can configure it like this

**`5 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento indexer:reindex`**

Here I assumed that you want to run the cron every day after 5 minutes midnight.

Comment: Thanks ! is that any coding part need to manage ?

Comment: No, no coding required for cron setting.

Answer (score 1):

When you set main Magento 2 cron job, reindexing will be done automatically.

You can set main Magento 2 cron as follows.

```
#~ MAGENTO START
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END
```

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html